# Apply SP3 on SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn AAGs

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups, high-availability

If Always-On is configured, while applying Service Pack, should I:

- Directly move SQL Server Instance (Secondary Replica) to make it passive and apply Service Pack
- Or First move Availability Group and then move SQL Server Instance (Secondary Replica) and finally apply patch and restart the Server.

Can you please let me know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before an upgrade, you should:

- Perform a full backup of every database
- Try a manual failover. Make sure the AG fails over a Synchronous replicas and that the synchronization state of the replicas is `SYNCHRONIZED`
- Disable automatic backups on Secondary while they are being upgraded
- Disable automatic backups on Primary before the upgrade of Primary
- Do not upgrade Primary before any or all of the Secondary.

Then here is the [Rolling Upgrade Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178483.aspx):

1. Remove automatic failover on all synchronous-commit replicas
2. Upgrade all asynchronous-commit secondary replica instances
3. Upgrade all remote synchronous-commit secondary replica instances
4. Upgrade all local synchronous-commit secondary replica instances
5. Manually fail over the AG to a (newly upgraded) local synchronous-commit secondary replica (see [Perform a planned manual failover of an Always On availability group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/perform-a-planned-manual-failover-of-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) on Microsoft Docs)
6. Upgrade or update the local replica instance that formerly hosted the primary replica.
7. Configure automatic failover partners as desired.

Comment: Hi, @Julien can you confirm the correct steps to follow for failover without outage or data loss? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/perform-a-planned-manual-failover-of-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hi @Senior Systems Engineer, it seems to be the current and valid documentation indeed. You can open a new question if you are missing something. I will add it to the above procedure for clarity... Thanks